# Reactjs Navigate to another page when Button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, navigation

import React from 'react'

import Form from './Form'

function Login() {

```
return (
 
    <div
    style={{
      backgroundColor: '#008BA8',
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
      left: '0',
      width: '50%',
      height: '100%'
    }}
>
<div> <Form /></div>
<div><img style={{paddingLeft: '1180px', }}src = "/Images/3.JPG" alt=""/></div>

<h1 style={{color: 'white',paddingTop: '150px', paddingRight: '300px'}}>WELCOME BACK</h1>

<p style={{color: 'white',paddingRight: '140px', fontSize: '30px'}}>We're happy to see you again</p>

<button style = {{backgroundColor: '#EF7F1B',borderRadius: '15px',width: '300px', height: '60px', color: 'white',fontSize: '20px',marginRight: '40px' }}>FORGOT PASSWORD</button>
```

```
);
```

}

export default Login

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? 
Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result
please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can have a look into react routing for basic examples on different ways to implement this https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

you can use useHistory function, [`useHistory` function is part of react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/use)

```
const history = useHistory()
```

and then in your button `onclick` you can type

```
onClick = {() => history.push("your link")}
```

Comment: i dont have a link. i should link another component which is another page which i have created.